# Класс объявил, что он сопоставлен с" адресом ", но это не поле связанного типа

Tags: java

Есть два поля - логин и пароль,если нажимаю регистрация, выдает:

> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException:
>   "com.eventim.petshop.entities.Pet.treatments" declared that it is mapped by "address", but that is a not a field of the related type.

Не пойму, что имеется ввиду, нет связи чего с чем?

Вот классы:

Pet:

```
package com.eventim.petshop.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Collection;

@Entity(name = "PET")
public class Pet {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToMany (mappedBy="address", fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<Treatment> treatments;

    public Collection<Treatment> getTreatments() {
        return treatments;
    }
}
```

Treatment:

```
package com.eventim.petshop.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

@Entity(name = "Treatment")
public class Treatment {

    @ManyToOne(optional=false, cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="pets")
    private Pet pets;


    @Column(name = "preis")
    private BigDecimal preis;


    public BigDecimal getPreis() {
        return preis;
    }

    public void setPreis(BigDecimal preis) {
        this.preis = preis;
    }   
}
```

сам Login:

```
package com.eventim.petshop.Login;

import com.eventim.petshop.FacesUtils;
import com.eventim.petshop.entities.Customer;
import com.eventim.petshop.entities.CustomerRepository;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.Serializable;

@ManagedBean
public class Login implements Serializable  {

    @EJB
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    private String password;
    private String login;

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password1) {
        this.password = password1;
    }

    public void doLogin(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        Customer customer;
        try {
            customer = customerRepository.findUserByLoginAndPassword(login, password);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        FacesUtils.putUserId(customer.getId());
        redirectToOverview();
    }

    public void registerNewUser(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        Customer customer = customerRepository.createCustomer(login, password);
        FacesUtils.putUserId(customer.getId());
        redirectToOverview();
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    private void redirectToOverview() {
        FacesUtils.redirect("overview.xhtml");
    }
}
```

Comment: а если это OneToMany (mappedBy="address", fetch= FetchType.EAGER) поменять на это  OneToMany (mappedBy="pets", fetch= FetchType.EAGER)?

Comment: тогда вылезает com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/index.xhtml - Ansicht /index.xhtml 
не может быть восстановлено.

Comment: Эта ошибка уже не связана с проблемой из вопроса.
`@JoinColumn(name="pets")` - вот тут нужно указывать поле из класса `Pet`, по которому таблицы будут соединяться. Например `id`

Comment: ну простите, вы задали вопрос - я ответил. ошибка, которая у вас вылетала, больше не вылетает. то, что у вас там тонна проблем - это уже совершенно другая сторона медали

Comment: нет,вы меня не правильно поняли, ваш ответ правильный, это уже другая проблема была